# Can't set Target Audience property for list view webpart into a custom list with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, powershell, audience-targeting

I have tried to set target audience property with the lines code:

```
#Create client context
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl);
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Admin, (convertto-securestring $AdminPassword -asplaintext -force));
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();

#Get current web
$spoWeb = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($spoWeb)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get task list
$tasklist = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ABCTasks")
$ctx.Load($tasklist)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get hide view pages of the task
$taskpages = $tasklist.RootFolder.Files
$ctx.Load($taskpages)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get view taskpages of the task list
foreach($taskpage in $taskpages){
    #Write-Host $taskpage.Name
    if($taskpage.Name -eq "ABCUserView.aspx"){
        $ctx.Load($taskpage)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        break
    }
}

#Get webpart manager from the task page
$wpm = $taskpage.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Shared")
$ctx.Load($wpm)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get all of webpart of the task page
$webparts = $wpm.WebParts
$ctx.Load($webparts)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get webpart and set target audience for the view
$webpart = $webparts[0]
$ctx.Load($webpart)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

$webpart.WebPart.Properties["AuthorizationFilter"] = "ABC User Group;;"
$webpart.SaveWebPartChanges();

$ctx.Load($webpart);
$ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

After execute the lines code and open the **ABCUserView.aspx** page, this page is blank. The list view webpart doesn't display with the current user and users of **ABC User Group** was targeted and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try it as below:

```
$webpart.WebPart.Properties["AuthorizationFilter"] = ";;ABC User Group"
```

or

```
$webpart.WebPart.Properties["AuthorizationFilter"] = ";;;;ABC User Group"
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I have ever try it like that.